# Docker nginx self-signed certificate - can't connect to https

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt

I have been following a few tutorials to try and get my SSL cert working with my docker enviroment. I have decided to go down the route of a self-signed certificate with letsencrypt. I have generated the certificate with the following command

```
certbot certonly --manual \
  --preferred-challenges=dns \
  --email {email_address} \
  --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory \
  --agree-tos \
  --manual-public-ip-logging-ok \
  -d "*.servee.co.uk"
```

*NOTE: I am using multi tenancy so I need the wildcard on my domain*

This works, the certificate has been generated on my server. I am now trying to use this with my docker nginx container.

My docker-compose.yml files looks like this

```
...
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: docker/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 433:433
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    depends_on:
      - app
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
...
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine

COPY ./fullchain.pem /etc/nginx/fullchain.pem
COPY ./privkey.pem /etc/nginx/privkey.pem

ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ADD default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html

RUN addgroup -g 1000 laravel && adduser -G laravel -g laravel -s /bin/sh -D laravel

RUN chown laravel:laravel /var/www/html
```

I am copying the pem files into the nginx container so I can use them.

Here is my default.conf file which should be loading my certificate

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name servee.co.uk;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }  

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }  
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name servee.co.uk;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/privkey.pem;

    index index.php index.html;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://servee.co.uk; #for demo purposes
    }
}
```

The nginx container builds successfully and when I bash into it I can find the pem files. The issue is when I go to https://servee.co.uk I just get Unable to connect error. If I go to http://servee.co.uk it works fine.

I'm not sure what I have missed, this has really put me off docker because its such a pain to get SSL working so hopefully its an easy fix.

Comment: HTTPS uses port 443 by default but you're opening (only) 433. 433 is not 443. BTW, cert from LetsEncrypt is NOT self-signed. In PKI self-signed is a term of art that means signed by the same key(pair) as in the certificate; it has nothing to do with you _requesting_ or even _directing_ issuance by a CA.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you so much, I can't believe I made this type! Thank for also explaing what a sef signed cert is thats really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your docker-compose.yml file to use port 443 instead of 433 to match your nginx.conf. Try the below docker-compose.yml file.

```
...
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: docker/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    depends_on:
      - app
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
...
```